# Regexp-Search for similar lines-different words

Tags: regex

There are these lines:

```
assert json.error1.code == "1"
assert json.error.code  == "2"
assert json.error.code  == "3"
assert json.error1.code  == "4"
```

And I want to find all lines like

```
assert json.[anyword].code  == "3"
```

where anyword could be anything except error
So in my example, the first and 4th line.

Hi could I do that?

I tried something like

```
^.*(?!error)\.code.*$
```

but did not work, it matches all lines although I put a negation on error word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^.*(?!error)\.code.*$` regex matches any 0+ characters but a newline at the start of the string, then backtracks to find a character that is not followed with `error` substring, then a `.code` substring, and then 0+ characters other than a newline up to the end of string/line.

You can use

```
^(?!.*\.error\.).*\.code\s*==.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD1iA3/1) (matching the first and fourth lines you supplied). The `(?!.*\.error\.)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the string (line) contains a `.error.` substring.

**Pattern details**:

- `^`  - start of a line/string (depends if you use MULTILINE modifier or not)
- `(?!.*\.error\.)` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if there is `.error.` somewhere on the line/in the string - also depends on the DOTALL modifier)
- `.*` - any 0+ characters (other than a newline without the DOTALL modifier)
- `\.code` - a literal `.code` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `==` - a literal `==` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ characters (other than a newline without the DOTALL modifier)
- `$` - end of string/line (depends if you use MULTILINE modifier or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
'assert\sjson\.(?:(?!errors).*)\.code\s+==\s+"\d"'
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jG3uK7/5

Note that your negative look-ahead doesn't worked as you expect because you need yo precede the `.*` with that negative look-ahead and put them within a capture group.